# javafx + javascript on desktop app

Tags: javascript, desktop, javafx

I don't have any experience in JavaFX and I know a little about javascript. I want to develop a desktop app in JavaFX and adding some javascript functionality in JavaFX code. I have a .js file with the functions I need to use, but I don't know how to use them.
What are the main steps for doing it? I've been told it is possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scripting](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#scripting) and [script event handlers](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#script_event_handlers) in an [fxml document](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/jfxpub-fxml_get_started.htm).

You can also embed a [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm) to process HTML and JavaScript.